# Post-doctorate or equivalent "entry level" job

Tags: mathematics, job-search, job, machine-learning

I'm a PhD student in pure math hopefully defending my thesis in 9 months. This is exactly the period in which one has to look for post-doctoral positions or for an entry level job. I have recently become intersected in machine learning and learned some basics of it myself. I have some raw project on Github and an idea for another one in my head. The university even gave me to TA a machine learning class for Bsc so I guess I know a thing or two. I'm now in a crossroad  -- I wish to take a job which includes some "research aspects" but related to ML as I think it's quite cool and helpful "to the world".

The last few years have been very difficult for me due to challenging relations with various people in my group and my advisor calling me an imposter several times ("Are you idiot? Do you live in a fake reality like the last POTUS?!"). That made me take a decision not to look for a tenure track position in academy and to look for a place in which my skills are more appreciated and in which I can work out research problems in larger collaborations.

I wonder whether I should take nevertheless post-doctoral position in machine-learning, to strengthen my background and knowledge or apply directly to an entry-level job outside academy. I will have 3 papers by the end of my phd but none of which are related to applied math (albeit 2 of which are related to pure probability). I also have an offer from the guy I'm tutoring to work under him next year but I feel like doing post-doc in another campus of the same university is not precisely "a decent leverage" for future positions/jobs.

What would you do in my place? More importantly, can one with similar experience (moving from pure to ML for instance) can elaborate on his/her path including the difficulties?

Comment: Is it just that your advisor has extremely poor people skills? Otherwise known as a jackass?

Comment: @Buffy, he's very social with other people but with me somehow he is a bit tough. I had with him a talk on my future last year and he said something like "Indeed  I'm a hard person but that's because your education was poor albeit I'm partially accountable for not asking you to retake your Msc from scratch. As a matter of fact you have no future in our group so either go to industry or take another direction in your research. That's why we changed our initial problem to one more achievable to you". Speaking of which, his last student dropped as the problem was too hard, so I don't know.

Comment: There's no shortage of individuals with some sort of background in machine learning, and as you no doubt know it's also a field exploding rapidly in its core ideas, algorithms, and software implementations. In an industrial setting an entry level position tends to implement senior researchers' ideas and do lots and lots of training of models. To move beyond that you will understand the organization's goals, identify appropriate projects and sell them to leadership, then execute with the help of new entry level staff. I'm sorry for you if your advisor is half as crass as he sounds in your post.

Comment: @Aruralreader I agree there is no shortage but on the other hand, the domain advances so fast because many people bring their own eyes and perspectives for large collaborations freely, unlike in pure math. Also, I know that my home country is quite strong in ML but they don't have "that" strong academical community like here so I can bring my own unique perspective after all. Words cannot explain how much I learned from my advisor, regardless of his horrendous attitude.